# MYSQL - Error de compilación en .NET

Tags: mysql, .net, vb

El error me aparece en esta línea, tal vez alguien puede decir como instanciarlo de forma correcta:

Este es el código:

```
Dim cCon As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server =localhost; database=facturacionelectronica;user id=root;password=Menatics2018;port=3306;")
```

Este es el mensaje que tengo:

> error BC30002: No está definido el tipo 'MySqlConnection' error
>   BC30002: No está definido el tipo 'MySqlDataAdapter'

Answer (score 1):

> Fuente y créditos: [VB.NET MySQL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190631/4092887) en Stack Overflow "en inglés".

---

Es probable que no hayas descargado el componente necesario para la conexión con bases de datos en MySQL.

Puedes descargar el componente requerido en la [página de MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html).

Descargando e instalando el componente requerido para la conexión con bases de datos MySQL, puede usar este ejemplo para intentar la conexión:

Ejemplo:

```
Imports System.Data

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Tutorial1
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...")
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        conn.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("Done.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Fíjate bien que *(en el ejemplo adjunto)* se usa los `Imports`:

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Los cuales son necesarios para usar `MySqlConnection` y demás clases de conexión con bases de datos MySQL.

Comment: necesitas mejorar mucho tu aporte, si te das cuenta de la respuesta en inglés es muy detallada, entonces tradúcela y escribela aqui

Comment: @shadow editada la respuesta. Espero que así sea mas clara para el OP y para el resto de la comunidad. Cualquier ajuste que consideres deba hacer, por favor, deja un comentario para mejorar la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: me parece perfecta asi entonces +1